# JQuery/PHP - Overlay another page on keypress

Tags: php, jquery, css, keyboard

I'm trying to make a page "overlay" when the user presses the keyboard key T or P. With the code below, I am able to make the page turn blank, however, I would like to be able to display another html page or other text while the other disappears. When the user presses T or P again, it returns to there previous window.
Here is my current code:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    var key = e.which;
    if (key == 116) {
        // if the user pressed 't':
        if(!$("body").hasClass('active'))
            $("body").addClass('active');
        else
            $("body").removeClass('active');
    }
});

 <style>
    .active{opacity:0;}
 </style>
```

NOTE: I'm using style tags for testing purposes.
Please, if you have any suggestions on how to make one object hide, and another one appear please let me know. I would really appreciate it. A JSfiddle would be much appreciated if possible.
Thank you so much for reading!
Toby.

Comment: Maybe you can put your two different blocks of content into two different `div` tags inside the `body` tag.  Then toggle the active class (inversely) on both divs when you press button.  So when you press 't', you make `<div id="1">` remove active class and add active class to `<div id="2">`.  Then when you press again, do the opposite.  Perhaps instead of changing the opacity for the divs, you might want to toggle display from hidden to whatever and back.  That way they can occupy the same space when showing.  I'll write somethin up later tonight if you need me to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code that are notable.

### 1. You are hiding the body.

**Everything** should be within your document body, so if you hide the whole document, you can't see anything! Put your content into separate divs so that you can hide each one independently.

### 2. You are not fading

In order to fade, you either have to use CSS3 transitions or use a jQuery animation.

See **[this example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ER9gF/5/)** for an idea. Press 'T' to alternate between the red and blue divs (*you'll have to click on the div to put your focus on the document*). I use a placeholder class `.hidden` (which has **no styles** attached; it is just  a placeholder) to keep track of which div is visible and hide/show accordingly.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).keypress(function(e) {
        var key = e.which;
        if (key == 116) {
        // if the user pressed 't':
            if($(".red").hasClass("hidden"))
            {
                $(".red").removeClass("hidden").animate({
                    opacity: "1"
                }, 500).css("z-index", 1);
                $(".blue").addClass("hidden").animate({
                    opacity: "0"
                }, 500).css("z-index", 0);
            }
            else
            {
                $(".blue").removeClass("hidden").animate({
                    opacity: "1"
                }, 500).css("z-index", 1);
                $(".red").addClass("hidden").animate({
                    opacity: "0"
                }, 500).css("z-index", 0);
            }
        }
    });

});
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ER9gF/5/)

Comment: This is close to perfect.
The only last problem I am having is that it "reloads" the attributes on the page. For example, I have a game running on the page, when they press "t" it hides perfectly. When they press "t" again it restarts the "code" for the game. When I set the opacity down, it did not do this. Any suggestions to keep them loaded but just hide them in the background?
Thank you so much!

Comment: @user2957677 What is it missing?

Comment: Sorry, I pressed ENTER by accident :).

Comment: You could try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ER9gF/5/ The only thing that will be an issue here is z-indexing. Notice the way I set the CSS of the z-index whenever T is pressed. The red div will never be able to receive clicks while it is below the blue one, so you'll have to set the z-index of the visible element to be the highest.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either :(.
You can see the "test" at http://imdoingwork.com/blabla.php.
Notice how if you press "play" wait for the game to load. Press "t", then notice how the game goes back to the "play" menu. The game is getting reset. Any ideas?
Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Sorry, I think I may have got this working. I'll keep you posted. Thanks SOOO much for this.

Comment: Hello, I was wondering if you can help me get this working cross browser/ customize it abit. I can pay you for your services if you wish, if you're interested please add me on skype (mellor12345) or email me at tobymulberry@hotmail.com.